# Color management for editing iphone 14 pro max in Da Vicci resolve 18.4

Tags: davinci-resolve, iphone

Could anyone suggest the colour-management settings in da Vinci resolve for editing 14 pro max footage?

Here is the metadata for my footage

[image: Meta data]

and here is the resolve [image] Thanks a lot.